# Django Serializer only serializing objects with many=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a serializer

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

and in the viewset,

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = Store.objects.first()
    ser = StoreSerializer(data=obj)
    if ser.is_valid():
        pass
    print(ser.data)
    return Response(ser.data)
```

this method is returning just an empty dict `{}` as the response. When defining the serializer as

```
ser = StoreSerializer(data=[obj], many=True)
```

the object is getting serialized. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't have to call ser.is_valid() when you passing a models data, just pass without data key, ser = StoreSerializer(obj) print(ser.data)

Comment: thank you @Luiz can you write it down as an answer so that I can accept it and mark it answered? what is the use of data keyword? can you add that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are passing a models data to a ModelSerializer you don't need to call the function

```
serializer.is_valid()
```

So you can just pass the data without the data key as

```
ser = StoreSerializer(obj)
print(ser.data)
```